# Djoser override activation email with template

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-templates, djoser

I've been scouring for more information about how to do this, but there seems to be little to no documentation help.

Essentially want I want to do is make a new template for the activation email so the link can start with localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8000 (I'm using Vue for the frontend post request that's why)

I managed to find this: https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/templates/email/activation.html
but when I added it to my own project, the default Djoser template is still being used.

**This is how my settings.py looks like:**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**My activation URL which works if the 8000 is replaced by 3000 manually:**

```
 'ACTIVATION_URL': 'registration/activate/{uid}/{token}',
```

**templates/email/activation.html:**

```
{% block subject %}
{% blocktrans %}Account activation on {{ site_name }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock subject %}

{% block text_body %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email becaus!!!!!!e you need to finish activation process on {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page to activate account:" %}
{{ http }}://{{ localhost:3000 }}/{{ {% url 'registration/activate' uidb64=uid token=token %} }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
```

Comment: Note: if you have inline CSS in your custom template, your HTML template may not load. So, you may want to look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73581733/15993687)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suppose you need to override `email.ActivationEmail`, for example to `core/email.py`

```
from djoser import email


class ActivationEmail(email.ActivationEmail):
    template_name = 'email/activation.html'
```

and add it to your settings.py

```
DJOSER = {
    'EMAIL': {
            'activation': 'core.email.ActivationEmail'
    }
}
```

Here are emails which can be overwritten [link](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/conf.py#L66)

Comment: Thanks! this worked. Initially I tried it and couldn't get it to work since I put the activation file in a template folder that was in my project not the app. I ended up just taking a break from this issue and revisited it today. Works fine now :)

Comment: do you know how does one personalizes username/first_name in the overridden email?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo If I got you right, you need to use {{user.first_name}}  {{user.last_name}}. user is in context already

Comment: djoser uses django-templated-mail wich uses django templates, so if you're getting template not found, check out the docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the `DOMAIN` and `SITE_NAME` in the settings.py file instead of changing the template.
Just put DOMAIN = ('localhost:3000') and SITE_NAME = ('YOUR_SITE_NAME')

```
DOMAIN = ('localhost:3000') 
SITE_NAME = ('YOUR_SITE_NAME') 
DJOSER = {
    ...
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62586798/6568539 (I found that we don't need to use "config" as mentioned in this answer)

Comment: do you know how does one personalizes username/first_name in the overridden email?

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the Djoser email classes and settings.py, You can override the html templates in your project's template directory using the concepts [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory)

You just simply have to create a new folder named **email** in your 'templates' folder and in it create html files with the exact names for the email templates that you would want to customize/override.

For example if you want to customize the password reset email, your custom file path should resemble this :

```
projectName/templates/email/password_reset.html
```

[Here](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/tree/master/djoser/templates/email) is a full list of all the Djoser email templates that you can customize

Answer (score 0):

I found this closed thread and it did do the job of allowing me to render out a custom template. Might want to check [this](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/issues/239#issuecomment-696188634)

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Pavlo Naumenko works for me too so thanks a lot. But just a small note: I have to change the name of the file (I couldn't use "activation.html" on my own template). If I use it, django keeps sending the default template. Don't know why.
In case someone happens that too. I was using django 3.2.3 with djoser 2.1.0

Answer (score -3):

it's working! I've just changed `activation.html` file in
`~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djoser/templates/email`
without any other changes

Comment: Hello new contributor!  It would be helpful if you can describe what you did and why it worked.

Comment: Djoser has an activation template, it uses it by default, so I found the template it's in djoser/templates/email, filename is activation.html I change the file content and save it. and it worked without any code change

Comment: @Anas Ahmad That is not a good way to do it. If you reinstall Djoser `pip install djoser` that code you have written will get overwritten.

Comment: it's not a problem, I save the html in myproject folders and I copy them after re-installation.

Comment: Yes but it's overall bad practice, is what he is trying to say. Whenever you change something in a dependency, you should always make sure that's represented in your projects code, using overrides or similiar.